# how to access topmost parent window

Tags: jquery

i have a a parent window and inside it i have one more sub parent window and then i have a child window.Nw my problem is that i want to access my topmost parent window from bottommost childwindow.i was using window.opener but i m not able to access my parent window from bottom most child window..plz help.how to use it using jquery or java script.

Answer (score 4):

I'm asuming you are talking about frames? Then you can use `window.top` to access the topmost frame.

Comment: Thanks Marius,No we are not using frames.Plz suggest an alternate to access  parent window from bottom most child.
* We are not using frames.

Comment: Then what are you using? How can you have a child window inside another window without a frame? Do you mean popups? Is one window opened and then that window opens another window? Try window.opener.opener.

Comment: Yeah marius,pop up inside pop up,i used window.opener.opener but its not working :( .Plz help.

Answer (score 3):

Kind of obvious I guess...

```
for (var topopener = window; topopener.opener; topopener = topopener.opener);
alert("topmost window = " topopener.document.title);
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code will give the top window

```
var win = window;
var topWindow = null;
while (win = win.opener) 
{ 
 topWindow = win; 
} 
if(topWindow != 'undefined' && topWindow != null )
{ 
  return topWindow;
}
```